# Require all ISO images for Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I do not want to use internet to make online packages installation, instead I want to install the complete installation on multiple machines from local DVDs...

Where can I get the entire packages?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get that on disc for Ubuntu (Ubuntu has more software in the repositories then Debian, and the full Debian is 10 DVDs for i386 and another 10 for x86_64). You **can** set-up a [mirror](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors). Remember the guidelines on that link, and especially that the expected size is approximately 642 gigabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I never tried this, but take a look at this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1914054

He uses "apt-offline" to update his packages on the offline machine.
But: This requires some other machine with internet-access to download the updates.

**Note**: This only works, if you want to **update** your machine.

If you want to **upgrade** an existing machine (say 12.04) to 14.04 or something similar, this solution will most likely fail.

But in your question, you also mention "the complete installation". 
If you want to install the new system, you can download the ISO from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop, but this will also need internet-connection.